# What is the opposite of SetDefault() in wxPython 4?

Tags: wxpython

In a simple GUI, I use `SetDefault()` on a button when the user has filled in the necessary text fields so that it's obvious that if the user now presses the return key, the button will be pressed. How do I "undo" the default setting once it is set? `SetDefault()` in wxPython does not take an argument, so I cannot call `SetDefault(False)`, and I cannot find a suitable API call to reverse the default state.

How is one supposed to reverse or undo the actions of a `SetDefault()` call in wxPython?

Comment: SetDefault() to a different button or use `self.SetFocus()`

Comment: @RolfofSaxony If only it were that easy. There is no other button that can logically be set as an alternative default in the situation, and `SetFocus()` doesn't take an argument to let me unset the focus on the button. Is your idea to set focus on something that isn't a button?

Comment: I see that you have come up with a solution but the idea behind using `self.SetFocus()` is that it moves the focus to the frame itself, rather than the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, as I have now learned, is to use `Enable()` and `Disable()` on the button.  What I was trying to accomplish with "undoing" `SetDefault()` is actually what `Disable()` does. Here is an abridged version of the working code now:

```
...
self.login.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.on_text)
self.password.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.on_text)
....
self.cancel_button = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Cancel")
self.cancel_button.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.on_escape)
self.ok_button = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "OK")
self.ok_button.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.on_ok_enter_key)
self.ok_button.SetDefault()
self.ok_button.Disable()
....
def on_text(self, event):
    if self.login.GetValue() and self.password.GetValue():
        self.ok_button.Enable()
    else:
        self.ok_button.Disable()
```